How to add shadow effect in the editText Android?
I would like to put this shadow effect in my project (fist imgae), but I cant figure it out, there is any native way to do it in Android Studio?

These are the settings of it (second image):

I tried to use elevation in the activity file, but it doesnt seem to create what I want
